# Shapefile of Baden-Württemberg and Rhineland-Palatinate with district boundaries

Tags: shapefile, data, germany

Can anyone help me find shapefiles of German states Baden-Württemberg and Rhineland-Palatinate (including their districts)?

Answer (score 2):

You can download them directly from the state department for cartography as these are listed as *open data*.

[State Departement for Cartography and Geodesy - Open Data](http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/geodaten/gdz_rahmen.gdz_div?gdz_spr=eng&gdz_akt_zeile=5&gdz_anz_zeile=0&gdz_user_id=0)

Answer (score 1):

This page https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/ offers you all available boundaries from the openstreetmap project. For the states you mention, it is down to suburb level.

Alternatively, http://www.gadm.org/country offers shapefiles down to Landkreis level for Germany.

Comment: Url is outdated, page moved to https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/

Answer (score 0):

You could use free and open OpenStreetMap (OSM) data. They are licensed under Open Database License (ODbL).

Open this URL for Baden-Württemberg: http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=(rel(62611);%3E;);out;
and this one for Rhineland-Palatinate: http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%28rel%2862341%29;%3E;%29;out;

Open the files in Quantum GIS and "Save As" Shapefile.
The difference between both urls is the "id". This id represents the OSM-relation. Every administrative boundary exists as a single OSM-relation.

In the OSM-Wiki you can find the ids of other "Bundesländer": http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:Grenze#Bundesl.C3.A4ndergrenze_-_admin_level.3D4